# How to replace "as" tool with the x86 version on REHL?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, rhel

I ran into below problem on RHEL while using gcc to compile a C file.

```
 [test]$ gcc hello.c 
 as: unrecognized option '-Qy'
```

Then found my "as" is the MIPS version:

```
 [test]$ as -v
 GNU assembler version 2.13.2 (mips-dec-ultrix42) using BFD version 2.13.2
```

So I tried to remove MIPS utilities and reinstall x86 gcc and x86 binutilites by issuing:

```
 sudo yum erase binutils-mips64-linux-gnu.x86_64
 sudo yum install gcc-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64
 sudo yum install binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.34.el6.x86_64
```

But the problem still occurred. Anyone has any clue on how to replace my "as" with a x86 version?

BTW, Linux release info is as following:

```
  [test]$ lsb_release -a LSB Version:   
  :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:gaphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-    4.0-noarch
  Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation Description:    Red Hat
  Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.3 (Satiago) Release:        6.3
  Codename:       Santiago
```

Comment: type `which as` and perhaps edit your `PATH` (e.g. in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`)

Comment: GCC is often built with explicit paths to utilities like `as` and `ld`. Perhaps `gcc -v` will give you more information. also: `gcc -print-prog-name=as` (or `ld`) might be useful.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Thanks for your answer. I originally issued "whereis -b as", it located to "/usr/bin/as" where I couldn't the MIPS version. Following your way, I used "which as" to find the right place "/myhome/mips-x86-linux/as".  Then I modified my $PATH in .bashrc and relogin to bash, the problem was resolved.